# Permission denied while running Kafka commands

Tags: apache-kafka

Iam using Kafka version kafka_2.8.0-0.8.1.1.
When i try to start the Kafka server using the following command:

`./kafka-server-start.sh /home/msruser1/hadoopcluster/kafka_2.8.0-0.8.1.1/config/server.properties`

permission denied appears on console:

`-bash: ./kafka-server-start.sh: Permission denied`

Any suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Run: `sudo !!` to execute previous command with elevated permissions.
You can also give yourself permission with `sudo chown -R msruser1 /home/msruser1/hadoopcluster`